# React Router display one component for all routes ( a header)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Have a question regarding react router.

I have a header item that I would like to display for all routes. And of course, I want this to be part of the  so that the user can click items from a nav.

Currently I have my `<Header />` outside of my `<Router>` and I guess this isn´t working since my router then don't know to re-render?

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Posts} />
        <Route exact path="/:category/:postId" component={PostDetails} />
        <Route path="/:category" component={CategoryView} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
```

And my header has for example a `<Link to="/">LOGO</Link>`

Comment: Did you try <Header /> inside <Router> using div above <Header />  ?

Comment: Is your problem that your route components are not re-rendering when you click nav links? I.e. moving from */category1* to */category2*

Comment: @dpetrini I have not tried that.

Comment: @SteveHolgado Thats correct

Answer (score 2):

My comment in answer:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div> 
          <Header />
          <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" component={Posts} />
           <Route exact path="/:category/:postId" component={PostDetails} />
           <Route path="/:category" component={CategoryView} /
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change location but the same route is matching, your component is not remounting, just receiving new props.

Therefore, you can use the **componentWillReceiveProps** hook to update your component using the new route params (e.g. *nextProps.match.params.category*):

```
...

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

  // Update component using nextProps

}

...
```