# How to display a common component for all routes in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js and i'm trying to create a dashboard layout where i want to render a sidebar(which will be common in all the routes) and based upon the click event of sidebar items i want to render different component. Although i have achieved this, but in first instance the sidebar is present with the loaded component but once i refresh the page, only the newly loaded component remains on the page and sidebar is vanished.

//This is my main page code;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Dashboard.css'
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
import Sidebar from "../SideBar/Sidebar";
import Charts from "../Charts/Charts";
import About from "../About/About"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        // this.state.aboutComponent = this.props.aboutComponent;
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Sidebar></Sidebar>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={"/"} component={Charts} />
                        <Route exact path={"/about"} component={About} />
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer></Footer>
                </div>
            </Router>

        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard
```

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import './Sidebar.css';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
import About from '../About/About';
// import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
    link: {
        textDecoration: 'none',
        color: theme.palette.text.primary
    },
    appBar: {
        zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
    },
    appBarShift: {
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: 36,
    },
    hide: {
        display: 'none',
    },
    drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    },
    drawerOpen: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    },
    drawerClose: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        width: theme.spacing(7) + 1,
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            width: theme.spacing(9) + 1,
        },
    },
    toolbar: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),

        // necessary for content to be below app bar
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    },
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
}));

export default function Sidebar() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [component, setComponent] = React.useState('user')
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const history = useHistory();


    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };


    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    return (
        // <Router>
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar
                position="fixed"
                className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
                    [classes.appBarShift]: open,
                })}
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <h1>SGGB</h1>
                    <div className="alignment">
                        <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
                            <h4>Menu</h4>
                        </Button>
                        <Menu
                            id="simple-menu"
                            anchorEl={anchorEl}
                            keepMounted
                            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                            onClose={handleClose}
                        >
                            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>

            <Drawer
                variant="permanent"
                className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
                    [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
                    [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
                })}
                classes={{
                    paper: clsx({
                        [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
                        [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
                    }),
                }}
            >

                <List>
                    <ListItem>
                        <IconButton
                            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
                                [classes.hide]: !open,
                            })}
                            onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
                        </IconButton>
                    </ListItem>

                    <ListItem>
                        <IconButton
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="open drawer"
                            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                            edge="start"
                            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
                                [classes.hide]: open,
                            })}
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </ListItem>

                    <Link to="/about" className={classes.link}>
                        <ListItem button key="about" >
                            <ListItemIcon>{<InfoIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="About" />
                        </ListItem>
                    </Link>
                </List>
            </Drawer>
        </div >
        // </Router>
    );
}
```

I have also referred to this post;

[React Router display one component for all routes ( a header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807549/react-router-display-one-component-for-all-routes-a-header)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the Route component inside a Switch component like this :

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Sidebar></Sidebar>
           <Switch>
            <Route exact path={"/"} component={Charts} />
            <Route exact path={"/about"} component={About} />
           </Switch>
        <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: I have tried wrapping it under <Switch> as well, but nothing happened. Still the  component is loaded as intended, but once i refresh the browser the sidebar disappears. I just hope I am not conceptually wrong.

Comment: Could you please provide your whole page code including the imports?

Comment: i have edited and posted the coding of entire page.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your Sidebar component. I have created a Sandbox with your components and it working fine for me : https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-banzai-gl4m1

Comment: Sir, I have added my Sidebar component code in the question; you can have a look at this. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Your sidebar component has been added to the Sandbox and it is working as expected. https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-banzai-gl4m1